# How to make User Field Type to restrict to SharePoint group using CAML Query (PowerShell)

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, powershell-ise

How to make User Field Type to restrict to SharePoint group using CAML Query, PowerShell.

```
$fieldXMLString = '<Field Type="User"
Name="'+$fieldName+'"
DisplayName="Primary Site Owner"
StaticName="'+$fieldName+'"
Group="'+$group+'"
UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"
Required="TRUE">
</Field>'
```

In the above code, I need to add another property which will point to SharePoint group. By doing this my control will be limited to a set of people.

This should be similar to SharePoint **Choose from** option using GUI.
Regards,
Vikrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UserSelectionScope="GroupID"` attribute to specify a group. `GroupID` is a group ID (integer).

You can see property description on the MSDN [field schema description page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575%28v=office.15%29.aspx)